# Set different maximum values for each field in the Bar Gauge | Grafana

Tags: queue, prometheus, alert, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I was trying to set up a dashboard so that I could monitor the number of messages within certain queues. The problem is that in order to create a suitable alert I need to set a maximum value for each of them.
The number of queues is really high so it is impossible to set this value manually, so I thought of retrieving it through another query.
At this point I don’t know how to apply this second query to the first one in order to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From above two options, select 'Overrides'.
You will find your metric there.

After that select Max as per given image below,

[image]

Comment: For me its not working. Overriding has no effect on gauge.